# Unity Errors after Update

Tags: unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I updated Unity today and i get 2 errors from times to times. I am pretty sure there are not from my scripts. How can i fix them?

```
SUCCEEDED(hr)

rc.right == m_GfxWindow->GetWidth() && rc.bottom == m_GfxWindow->GetHeight()
```

Comment: MonoDevelop or Visual Studio?

Comment: I use MonoDevelop for Unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug from Unity.

Re-Import the Project from the Editor.

**Assets** -> **Reimport All**.

Then from MonoDevelop go to **Build**->**Clean All** and then **Build** -> **Rebuild All**.

Close and restart Unity and MonoDevelop.

Comment: Thanks, is this a permanent fix or every time i load a project or make a new one i will have to do this again?

Comment: It should be a permanent fix. You can prove this by re-starting Unity again to see if there is still problem. Don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) answer if your problem is solved.